# Why is the CCSID shown as 0 in my MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i can see error as below from the error log of my QMGR:

```
- Process(27605.1) User(umts) Program(runmqtrm)
AMQ6047: Conversion not supported.

EXPLANATION:
WebSphere MQ is unable to convert string data tagged in CCSID 0 to data in
CCSID 0.
ACTION:
Check the WebSphere MQ Application Programming Reference Appendix and the
appropriate National Language Support publications to see if the CCSIDs  are
supported by your system.
```

That shows the CCSID is **0**; However, my current CCSID used by QMGR is **819**

```
dis qmgr ccsid
 1 : dis qmgr ccsid
 QMNAME(QMUMBFEA)                        CCSID(819)
```

So what's the problem with the CCSID? Is the MQ bug or sth else?

BTW, MQ version is **6.0.2.9**

Please help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: What did you do to make this happend?  How does the client call look like? There was a bug in WAS 6.1 resources.xml template that caused similar things regarding CCSID="0", is this related? 

However, try to go up to a supported version instead. If it's a bug, it's very likely removed by now. (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21584325).

Comment: @Petter can you give me the bug description link?

Answer (score 3):

Its not an MQ bug.

Its just that your putting application is setting the CCSID of your message equal to zero.
Now, the queue manager is trying to convert the message to its own CCSID, which fails.

You can escape from this conversion by turning off the channel conversion for the channel your application is using to put the message.

Comment: i can see the related process is 'runmqtrm' in the error output. As per your understanding, that 'runmqtrm' is the putting application here, right? And CCSID of QMGR should have been 0 also since my error is " cannot convert the data in CCSID 0 to data in CCSID 0. However, the CCSID of QMGR is 819 actually.